# FSCalendar (Swift 4) how to start the week on a particular date

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

I'm using FSCalendar and need the week view to always begin at today and then show a week's worth.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the first week day of the calendar.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.calendar.firstWeekday = 3
}
```

set 1 for sunday, 2 for monday and so on...

more information at: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FSCalendar/2.7.9/Classes/FSCalendar.html#//api/name/firstWeekday

Comment: Brilliant, mate. Thanks a lot!